# Порядок сортировки в подготовленных запросах

Tags: c++, sql, qt

Использую PosgreSQL 9.5, Qt5.7.

Хотелось бы иметь возможность управлять порядком сортировки в подготовленных запросах. Пытался сделать так:

```
QSqlQuery query;
QString columnName= 'act_id';
QString queryStr = "SELECT * FROM psi ORDER BY :order";
query.prepare(queryStr);
query.bindValue(":order", columnName);
query.exec();
```

В этом случае запрос выполняется без ошибок, но предложение `ORDER BY` игнорируется. Пока решил задачу путём ручной подстановки следующим образом:

```
QSqlQuery query;
QString queryStr = "SELECT * FROM psi ORDER BY %1 %2";
QString columnName = 'act_id';
query.prepare(queryStr.arg(columnName, order == Qt::AscendingOrder ? "ASC" : "DESC");
query.exec();
```

Известно, что ручное составление SQL-запросов может привести к проблемам, поэтому хотелось бы найти безопасный способ управлять порядком сортировки в запросах.

Comment: Что есть ```field``` и как оно кастится в корректное выражение для ```ORDER BY```? Можно пример его значения?

Comment: @tequillaz, обновил вопрос.

Comment: Вы запрос формируете вручную(!), порядок так или иначе указываете вручную(!) что в первом случае, что во втором. И то и другое - нормально.